# Slider to start after page had fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, load-order

Is there a way to start the full screen slider on my site after the preloader (query loader 2) has finished loading?

At the minute the preloader loads the page but once it has finished the slider is already half way through its first slide. 
What I would like is for the preloader to finish loading then the slider to start.
Things I have tried:

1.) Changing the load order by adding the call to query loader to the top of the page and putting the slider call at the bottom of the page.

2.) `jQuery.getScript()` which loaded the scripts in order but the slider had already started before the preloader had finished.
I tried `document.ready()` on the slider but this loaded it the same time as the preloader.

If you have any ideas as to where I'm going wrong here your help would be much appreciated.

I have put a link to my site as I didn't know which piece of code to add on here http://stavriaphotography.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple to make a function to check whether something has loaded. At a boolean to the function named 'loaded' and set its value to false. At the end of the preloader set its value to true. Then to start your slider, check whether loaded is true and if so: start the slider.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My jQuery knowledge is terrible but I understand your answer. I have written some code but it isn't working do you know what I'm doing wrong?                    setTimeout(function loaded() {
 loaded();
 loaded() = false;
 $("body").queryLoader2();
 loaded() = true;

 if( loaded() ) {
  $jQuery.getScript('rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js', 'rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js');
 }
}, 2000);

Comment: Loaded must be a variable, you write it as a function.

Comment: What you should do is var loaded = false; then add in your queryloader function at the end loaded = true; Then just check if the variable is true if(loaded) {startSlider();} You might want to use a loop to check it more often. Otherwise you could place the function call for startSlider() at the end of your queryLoader.

Comment: Thanks for that. Its working now. How would I add a delay of 2 seconds to the slider. I've tried setInterval but it doesn't seem to be working. My code so far is                              'code' $(document).ready(function () {
 var loaded = false;
 $('body').queryLoader2();
 var loaded = true;
 if(loaded) {
 setInterval(jQuery('.fullscreenbanner').revolution({
             //settings
          }, 3000));
 }
});

Comment: Try setInterval(function() { startSlider(); } , 2000); where startSlider() is your slide starting function.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer all my questions. Now it works like a charm! Have a great day!

Comment: This worked:

$(document).ready(function () { var loaded = false; $('body').queryLoader2(); var loaded = true; if(loaded) { setInterval( function() {jQuery('.fullscreenbanner').revolution({ //settings
})}, 1000); } });

@Max Langerak - Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can try setTimeout function of javascript.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // your script code
},1000);
```

you can change 1000 by your specific time limit after which you want to load your script.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have added a setTimeout to my code but it still doesn't work, my jquery knowledge isn't the best.